# Ruby on Rails : How to identify nested_form elements in javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

In a Ruby on Rails app, say I have an Item and an Order model as follows:

```
class Item
  :name
  :default_price
end 

class Order
  :customer
  :item_id
  :order_price
end
```

On an Order form, I can automatically populate the order_price field with the default_price using javascript and a json call as follows:

```
$(function (){  
    $('#order_item_id').live("change", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "/items/" + $(this).val(),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {   
        $('#order_price').val(data.item.default_price);
        },
        error: function(xhr,exception,status) {
          //errors....
        }
      });
    });
});
```

So far, so good. But now suppose I want to be able to list multiple items under a single order. In that case I could use a nested form and the following tables:

```
class Item
  :name
  :default_price
end 

class Order
  :customer
end

class OrderItem
   :order_id
   :item_id
   :order_price
end
```

The problem is that each nested OrderItem record has the same select ID, and a random order_price ID, eg:

```
<div class="fields">
  <ol>
    <li>  //first nested record
      <select id="order_item_id"></select>
      <input id="order_orderitems_attributes_0_orderprice"></input>
    </li>
    <li>  //second nested record
      <select id="order_item_id"></select>
      <input id="order_orderitems_attributes_###randomnumber###_orderprice"></input>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Clearly this causes problems for the javascript function.

How can I get my nested forms to play nicely with my javascript, so that selecting an item populates the corresponding price field?

I will need to pass an identifier for the nested record into the function so that the function runs when the select field is changed. I will also need to somehow identify the correct order-price field.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!!!

**EDIT**

Actually, I can get this working by using the .next() selector to find the next DOM element. i.e., in the js function

```
$('#order_item_id').live("change", function(e) {
    var current_price = $(this).next('.order-price')[0];
    .....
    success: function(data) {   
            $('current_price').val(data.item.default_price);
            },
    .....
```

but I'm feeling uncomfortable that each select field has the same ID. Is this something I should be concerned about? Are there any issues I should be thinking about?

EDIT 2

order form

```
<%= nested_form_for @order do |f| %>
    .....order fields
    <ol>
        <%= f.fields_for :orderitems %>         
    </ol>
    <p><%= f.link_to_add new_ico, :orderitems %></p>
    <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

orderitems partial

```
<li>
    <%= select(:orderitem,:item_id,@items.collect{|s|[s.name, s.id]},:prompt=>"select") %>
    <%= f.text_field :order_price, :class => "order-price" %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want changing the selected item for a `select` update the input right after it, right? If so, you can change your `success` handler to something like this:

```
function(data) {   
  // this refers to the select that its value has changed
  // and next('input') finds the input right after it
  $(this).next('input').val(data.item.default_price);
}
```

In order to make it more explicit that the input contains a specific value such as the order price, you can assign an HTML 5 `data-` attribute to it like this:

```
<%= f.input :order_price, :"data-field" => "order-price" %>
```

This way the CSS selector in your JavaScript would become a little bit more intuitive:

```
function(data) {   
  // this refers to the select that its value has changed
  // and next('input') finds the input right after it
  $(this).next('input[data-field=order-price]').val(data.item.default_price);
}
```

Worth mentioning that the `data-` attributes work even in HTML 4 if you are using a recent version of jQuery.

Comment: thanks @behrang, I had just come to the same solution as well! Do I need to be concerned that all select fields share the same ID? Any issues I should be planning for? (see my edits to the original question) thanks for your time!

Comment: @AndyHarvey I am guessing your form is not constructed correctly, otherwise different selects should have different ids. The ids are usually in a form like this: `foo[1]`, `foo[2]`, etc. Could you please post the code you are using for generating the forms. By the way, I have noticed that in some browsers having multiple elements with the same ID can confuse jQuery sometimes.

Comment: thanks @behrang. I've added the relevant view code to the question above.

Comment: of course, I was using the wrong select tag. Should be collection_slect, not select with nested_forms. Issue resolved, thanks for the pointers @behrang

Comment: @AndyHarvey Andy, good to know you pinpointed and fixed the problem. Always happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue by moving the `nested_form` gem's javascript file `jquery_nested_form.js` into my `/javascripts` folder (this should prioritise this file over the default one) then  changing the 'random' attribute Id to increment. This allows you to predict the input field id and thus easily identify it. Another benefit is that when the form is reloaded with error messages, the attribute names remain the same. I'm not a pro, but sofar this hasn't lead to any problems.

In my `jquery_nested_form.js`:

```
newId: function() {
  fieldNum += 1
  return fieldNum;
},
```